# How do I remove image width and height only, not iframes? Code included

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

The code I'm currently using in my wordpress functions file is this:

```
function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=("|\')\d*(|px)("|\')\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
```

The problem here is that it targets iframes too, so how would I rewrite the regex to say images only?

Comment: why not use js or jquery and just target classes with the height and width attributes you want to remove? otherwise look here pretty much the same question as yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562822/640727

Comment: I don't want to add additional javascript to the page load. I'm not sure which is more resource intensive, the js code, or the php though.

Thanks for the link, it might help.

Comment: wordpress comes with jquery baked in, all you would have to do is give all your images the same class ie `.removeWH` and then do `$('.removeWH').removeAttr('width height');` not that resource heavy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image tag scraper regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561166/image-tag-scraper-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [non capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) to search for the `img` tag before the other statements, something like

`(?:img.*)(width|height ?= ?['"].*['"])`

Which you can see working here: http://regex101.com/r/mI1bD5.

Note that this fails in a lot of simple cases (`iframe` on the same line as an `img` tag for example), but it should push you in the right direction.

Comment: Put this in place and it seems to work great. Thanks for the tip about catching them on the same line too. I'll be sure not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Trevor for helpful suggestion. 
Here's my revised expression that does a little better, but still not quite there.
`(?:<img.*){1}((width|height)=['"]\d*['"]) (?:.*\/>|>){1}`